# Angular 4 Passing ngx bootstrap datetpicker value to WebAPI

Tags: angular

I have used ngx-bootstrap datepicker in my Angular 4 project.
But when i am trying to pass the value to WebAPI , it 's gives me time also in the string.
For Eg: My Value: 2018-03-02T09:15:02.000Z

Is there any way in angular to extract only date not time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give a try on this

```
var today= new Date(); 
var date = today.getFullYear()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getDate(); 

console.log(date)
```

Comment: look for a change in formgroup using   
this.formgroupname.valueChanges.subscribe((form) => {})
and then convert it using the above code

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the date. Personally I use the DatePipe from Angular:

- Add private datePipe: DatePipe to your constructor
- And use it like this: this.datePipe.transform(date, format);